# Modify services to use from Container during test execution

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have to test some Commands which are using services that are taken from the container during execution.

It is possible to make the Command to use different services during test execution?

PS: Overriding the service definition in config_test.yml is not an option, since it will cause the basic flow of the application to break.

Comment: I forgot to say that I am developing in Symfony2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency injection container used by symfony exposes a `set` method you can use to change the service returned by the container:

```
$container->set('my.service.id', new InjectedService);
```

If you do this in the context of your test, you can change the class which is used for each test.

The signature of the set method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Sets a service.
 *
 * @param string $id      The service identifier
 * @param object $service The service instance
 * @param string $scope   The scope of the service
 *
 * @api
 */
public function set($id, $service, $scope = self::SCOPE_CONTAINER);
```

Have a look at the `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface` to see how it works in detail.